# JPA @PrePersist & LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I came up with interesting situation that I already know how to work around, but I was wondering if there is some elegant solution for this.

I have an Entity, which **can not** have a **@Versio** field since it is based on a legacy database, and the table has no column to have this kind of value.

Basically it is something like this:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private java.util.Date lastUpdated;
}
```

This is basically just for EULA (End User License Agreement) checking.
I want the Date to be updated when the eula has to be re-accepted (The new eula date is got from other place).

For that I was planning to use:

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
protected void setPersistTime() {
    this.lastUpdated = new Date();
}
```

The *@PrePersist* is called correctly when the entity is stored for the first time, but on the subsequent times the JPA seems to think that the entity is the same as before and the *@PreUpdate* won't be called as there is nothing to change.

I was planning to use

```
em.refresh(myEntity, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
```

But that won't work without the **@Version** which I cannot use due to the legacy db. (no version field I could use and the Date is of wrong type for it).

Btw. Using EclipseLink.

Comment: The solution is of course just to update this value by hand (or delete the old value and re-insert it), but I was just curious if there is actually a way just to use the 'JPA stuff' to achieve this?

Comment: And just to add... When I set the date manually, it is actually then updated by the @PreUpdate. :)